# Using different regions in AWS will increase cost?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

I have reached the maximum number of instance in US-EAST region, Will it cost more If I put my resource in another region?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can request to have the limit increased here:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws_service_limits.html

You can also use the AWS Simple Monthly Calculator costs in different regions:

https://calculator.s3.amazonaws.com/index.html